# comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r

Bom dia,

Tenho um dataframe cuja estrutura é dada por

```
> head(citationsAllYears)
  appln_id_cited appln_id_citn ano_prior
3            636      56755306      2008
4            636           644      2008
5            644      56755306      2008
6           1096     275471855      2007
7           1607      57977423      2004
8           1607      57977422      2004
>
```

Preciso fazer um filtro por ano, tal que, para cada ano, eu considere um subconjunto de linhas para os quais ano_prior <=ano, onde "ano" é um índice.
Geralmente, quando faço

```
links <- citationsAllYears[  citationsAllYears$ano_prior <= ano  ,    ]
```

Eu costumo ter o subconjunto que preciso. Já usei o mesmo esquema antes e sempre deu certo. Mas desde ontem, quando instalei alguns pacotes que o igraph requer, esta abordagem não funciona e obtenho a mensagem:

```
> Error in citationsAllYears$ano_prior <= ano : 
  comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Estou com a versão mais recente do R e do R-Studio. Onde está o problema?

Me desculpem se a pergunta é demasiado elementar, faz apenas dois meses que uso o R e estou aprendendo "em tempo real".

Não posso aplicar nenhum comando da família *apply pois apesar de ser mais eficiente, esta é uma parte mínima do que preciso fazer com milhões de dados e várias bases simultâneamente. E o meu notebook neste momento não me permite processar todos os dados com esses comandos. Logo, preciso particionar a análise um ano de cada vez.

Aqui o session.info()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] compiler  stats     graphics  grDevices
[5] utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] UsingR_2.0-5    Hmisc_3.17-4   
 [3] ggplot2_2.1.0   Formula_1.2-1  
 [5] survival_2.39-2 lattice_0.20-33
 [7] HistData_0.7-8  MASS_7.3-45    
 [9] dplyr_0.4.3     foreign_0.8-66 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5         cluster_2.0.4      
 [3] magrittr_1.5        splines_3.3.0      
 [5] munsell_0.4.3       colorspace_1.2-6   
 [7] R6_2.1.2            plyr_1.8.3         
 [9] tools_3.3.0         nnet_7.3-12        
[11] parallel_3.3.0      grid_3.3.0         
[13] data.table_1.9.6    gtable_0.2.0       
[15] latticeExtra_0.6-28 DBI_0.4-1          
[17] assertthat_0.1      Matrix_1.2-6       
[19] gridExtra_2.2.1     RColorBrewer_1.1-2 
[21] acepack_1.3-3.3     rpart_4.1-10       
[23] scales_0.4.0        chron_2.3-47       
>
```

Comment: Seu comando parece correto. Edite sua pergunta com o resultado de `sessionInfo()` para ficar mais fácil de entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Feito @daniel-falbel! Não sei o que mudou no software! Só pode ser isso mas estou travada! Devo reinstalar tudo?

Comment: Para corrigir rapidamente o seu problema você pdoe chamar explicitamente a função `[` usando: `links <- subset(citationsAllYears, citationsAllYears$ano_prior <= ano)`. Mas ainda não sei dizer o que pode estar causando o primeiro problema.

Comment: Infelizmente deu o mesmo problema. Acho que vou reinstalar tudo pois antes de instalar os pacotes do igraph eu não tinha problema nenhum com esses comandos. obrigada @daniel-falbel.

Comment: Acredito que reinstalar tudo não vai resolver o problema. Existe algum erro de comparação no seu código. O que dá `str(ano)` e `str(citationsAllYears)`?

Comment: Ambos do tipo numérico. @daniel-falbel. Recarreguei tudo de novo e simplesmente o erro sumiu! Nunca vi algo assim nestes dois meses. Obrigada pela ajuda! Abs.

Comment: Ok! Que bom que deu certo! Vou votar para fechar a sua pergunta porque não é um erro reproduzível.