# O que significa o termo "atômico"?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Vejo em algumas resposta/perguntas o termo "atômico".

Em programação, o que ele deve significar de fato?

Ex:

[comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133674/comparison-4-is-possible-only-for-atomic-and-list-types)

[Tem como auto incrementar o id no mongo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253821/tem-como-auto-incrementar-o-id-no-mongo/253825#253825)

Comment: Foi mal, @Renan. Deu uma confusão entre minhas edições e as tuas.

Comment: @LINQ no problemo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Atômico vem do átomo, ou seja, algo que é indivisível. Na computação usamos o termo quando algo é garantidamente feito por inteiro, não pode fazer apenas uma parte, ainda que tenha que descartar o que estava fazendo para garantir isso. Uma operação atômica não pode ser dividida em partes sem que cause algum problema.

Atualizar um valor inteiro é uma operação atômica na maioria das arquiteturas. Você não muda uma parte dele. Mudar um `decimal` ou `long` já pode não ser atômico porque ele pode ter mais que uma parte e se não tiver algum mecanismo que garanta a atomicidade, uma parte poderia ser mudada, e acontecer algo em seguida com esse valor e depois outra parte ser atualizada. Isso também é chamado de [linearização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability).

[Em banco de dados se usa muito o termo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), principalmente em transações. Isso quer dizer que ou a transação faz por completo ou ela faz nada, não pode fazer só uma parte. Se você faz uma compra a operação tem que emitir a nota fiscal, mudar o saldo do estoque, baixar o pedido, gerar o boleto, etc., tudo junto, se algo falhar nada disso pode ser feito, não pode fazer algumas dessas e deixar as outras pra lá.

Isso tem a ver com o estado. A preocupação não é se o algoritmo em si foi executado por completo, mas se o estado foi mudado por completo. O que não altera estado não tem problemas de atomicidade. Então o que um método retorna nada tem a ver com esse conceito, terá se o método altera algum estado dentro dele. Se essa alteração for feita por completo, ou nada for feito, ela será atômica. Se ele deixar mudar só uma parte por alguma razão ela não é atômica.

O fato de fazer a alteração de uma parte deixar essa parte alterada visível por alguma operação concorrente e depois fazer a outra parte, também quebra a atomicidade (embora tenha mais a ver com isolamento), mesmo que a operação se complete. Se tem mais de uma parte é divisível, então não é atômico. Por isso existem mecanismos para controlar que várias partes executem juntas por completo antes de deixar algo acessar aquilo. O travamento é o mecanismo mais óbvio.

Quando não há qualquer forma de concorrência a atomicidade não é importante. O problema é que existe concorrência em vários pontos onde não vemos. E o fato de não haver concorrência não significa que algo não pode ser atômico. Ou algo é atômico ou não é. Se precisava ser é outra questão.

Tem a ver também com [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). É raro observar esse problema em certas ocasiões e isso faz as pessoas negligenciarem o problema. Ele é pior justamente por ser raro. É difícil de reproduzir e saber o que está acontecendo. Por isso tem que fazer certo mesmo que não parece ser necessário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então um método que retorna true ou nada é atomico, e um método que pode retornar true, false ou uma exceção não seria, é isso ?

Comment: Não, nada a ver com isso, dei uma editada para melhorar.

Answer (score 13):

A palavra átomo vem do grego  *atomos*. Ela é formada pelas partes:

- *a*: radical que indica negação;
- *tomos*: que significa divisões.

Logo, um átomo é algo que é impossível de se dividir (até surgir <strike>o Albert Einstein</strike> a Marie Curie e esculhambar com essa parte da física).

Em programação, nós dizemos que uma coisa é atômica se ela não puder ser quebrada em mais partes. Geralmente isso é utilizado em bancos de dados, para uma sequência de operações que devem ser tratadas como uma operação só por motivos de consistência de informações.

Por exemplo, suponha que você queira me transferir dinheiro através de *Internet Banking*. A sequência de passos no banco de dados seria a seguinte:

1-) seu saldo é subtraído da quantia a transferir;
2-) meu saldo é aumentado pela mesma quantia;
3-) é lançado um registro de saída no log da sua conta;
4-) é lançada um registro de entrada no log da minha conta.

O que acontece se a conexão cair entre o passo 1 e o passo 2? Seu dinheiro some e vai pro limbo, sem jamais chegar à minha conta, e sem o log da saída não tem como recuperar aquela quantia.

Ao tornar essa sequência atômica, o banco garante que ou ela acontece, ou ela não acontece, pois ela é indivisível e todos os passos devem ocorrer como um só. Na prática, isso significa que as operações ficam em memória e só são persistidas todas de uma vez - se uma operação falhar, todas as operações são revertidas.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** É necessário que você saiba o que é uma thread para entender a explicação abaixo.

Todas as instruções que você faz em um computador são divididas em partes, isso acontece pela forma como a arquitetura do computador é construída, por exemplo:

```
if(x == 3){
    // faz alguma coisa importante aqui e depois zera o x
    x=0;
}else{
    x++
}
```

para que o computador seja capaz de fazer a verificação de **x == 3** ele divide isso em 8 partes.

Sabendo disso, imagine um programa que possui diversas threads, isso causa o que chamamos de situação de concorrência, exemplo: digamos que só existe duas threads, e a primeira chego no `if(x==3)` e logo em seguida ela irá zerar o valor de *x* porém essa ação não é *atômica*(ou seja não é executada de uma vez só.) e a segunda thread também chega no if antes da primeira conseguir zerar o *x* ou seja ela também ira entrar no `if`

Então quando trabalhamos com threads queremos que algumas ações sejam "atômicas", que em teoria quer dizer que ela seria executada de uma vez só, porem isso é impossível porque faz parte da arquitetura do computador, mas o sistema operacional consegue "burlar" a arquitetura e faz com que aquele ponto que foi sinalizado como atômico não seja acessado por outra thread até que ele seja liberado. Esse bloqueio e liberação é feito por meio de semáforos ou mutex, em java você tem classes que abstraem essa implementação para você.

Answer (score 4):

Atomicidade:
Uma transação deve ser uma unidade atômica de trabalho; ou todas as suas modificações de dados são executadas ou nenhuma delas é executada.
fonte: [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190612(v=sql.105).aspx)