# Por que passamos um objeto para o statement lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concorrência

Estou trabalhando com *multithreading* e caí em um caso de concorrência. Mais de uma *thread* acessou uma operação de I/O em um mesmo arquivo e por isso uma exceção foi disparada. Para resolver o problema, fiz assim:

```
private static object padlock = new object();

private static void SaveFile(string content) {
    lock (padlock) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Dir);
        File.AppendAllText(FilePath, content);
    }
}
```

O objeto `padlock` é passado para o `lock`. Eu aprendi como se fosse uma receita de bolo (o que é horrível!). Não sei por que preciso do objeto `padlock`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto tem a ver com [atomicidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253852/101). Isto garante que o objeto não poderá ser acessado por outras partes do código concorrentemente até que ele seja liberado, garantindo assim que o estado intermediário que ele esteja durante todo o bloco não seja acessível.

Isto é controlado pelo *framework*. Na verdade este código é apenas açúcar sintático para:

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = padlock;
try {
    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Dir);
    File.AppendAllText(FilePath, content);
} finally {
    if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(temp);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Lock.cs).

Portanto é a classe [`Monitor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que controla esse esse acesso.

Muitas vezes [usar o *lock* faz perder a vantagem da concorrência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101) ficando apenas com o ônus.

Note que a operação de travamento só está ocorrendo na aplicação e não no recurso externo (arquivo). Se for permitido o recurso externo ainda pode ser acessado por outras aplicações e dar problema. O travamento assim só está impedindo outra *thread* de executar o mesmo código ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 2):

Este objeto é que vai "*guardar*" a informação do lock.

Quando a primeira thread entrar no método e chamar o `lock`, o objeto `obj` (ou `padlock`, no seu exemplo) é que vai estar com o status `locked` e impedir uma outra thread de entrar.

Ele é apenas o objeto que guarda esta informação.

A partir do C# 4.0, a instrução lock é compilada deste jeito:

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = obj;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken);
    // Operação thread unsafe...
}
finally
{
    if (lockWasTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(temp); 
    }
}
```

Onde o método original é este:

```
private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

// Dentro de um método XYZ
lock (obj)
{
    // Operação thread unsafe...
}
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029804/how-does-lock-work-exactly)