# Como fazer uma mensagem de erro pra essa situação?

Tags: python, array

```
arq=open('filmes.txt','r')
filmes = arq.readlines()
def buscaPorGenero():

genero=str(input("Digite o gênero do filme: "))
while(True):
    for linha in filmes:
        linha = linha.split(";")
        if genero in str(linha[1]):
            print(linha[0])
    break
```

Quando o filme não estiver no arquivo, eu queria mostrar uma msg de erro mas não consegui, já tentei de várias maneiras com while e for e não achei uma que funcionasse.No meu arquivo txt as info estão separadas por `;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma variável de controle do tipo booleana. Eu nomeei de `achou`.

```
achou = False # inicializa a variável
while(True):
    for linha in filmes:
        linha = linha.split(";")
        if genero in str(linha[1]):
            achou = True # seta para verdadeiro se tem algum filme com esse gênero
            print(linha[0])
    break

if not achou: # se não encontrou, então...
    print("O gênero não foi encontrado :( ")
```

O valor de inicialização é falso, somente fica verdadeiro se passou por todas as iterações sem encontrar nenhum filme com o gênero a pesquisar.

Nesse exemplo que você deu, como o [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) disse, não tem necessidade do laço `while` infinito com um `break` logo quando acaba o `for`. Ficando então assim:

```
achou = False # inicializa a variável
for linha in filmes:
    linha = linha.split(";")
    if genero in str(linha[1]):
        achou = True # seta para verdadeiro se tem algum filme com esse gênero
        print(linha[0])
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Como está criando uma função para fazer a busca, não é interessante que você faça o `print`. Isso gera efeitos colaterais: nem sempre será desejado executar a função e obter o resultado no terminal, então o ideal é retornar os valores ao invés de exibí-los. Chamamos estas funções de *funções puras*, caso queira estudar mais sobre o assunto.

- [O que é uma função pura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/5878)
- [O que siginfica o termo "atômico"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253852/5878)
- [O que são "unidades de código"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/5878)

Aliás, fazer a leitura do valor dentro da função também rompe com a atomicidade da função; e se for desejado buscar os filmes de um gênero em específico? Terei que criar outra função para isso? Idealmente isso deveria ser um parâmetro da função.

Outra alteração que tomei liberdade em fazer foi alterar o modo de análise do arquivo. Você está separando os valores das colunas no arquivo de texto com um caractere de ponto e vírgula, `;`, isso claramente caracteriza o formato CSV, então não tem porquê não ler o arquivo como tal. Assim, seu arquivo poderia ser algo como, onde a primeira linha será os nomes das colunas:

**filmes.csv**

```
name;genre;id;year
O Hobbit;fantasia;343433434;2007
```

E no Python, podemos definir um gerador que buscará pelo gênero no arquivo. Os parâmetros serão o gênero que desejamos buscar e o arquivo onde será buscado. Para facilitar, podemos definir este segundo parâmetro com um valor padrão. Em seguida, abriremos o arquivo para leitura, definiremos um leitor de CSV e percorreremos as linhas, verificando se o filme pertence ao gênero desejado; se sim, este será retornado via `yield`, que é basicamente o `return` de um gerador.

```
import csv

def search_by_genre(genre, filename='filmes.csv'):
    """ Busca em um arquivo todos os filmes de um determinado gênero.

    Atributos:
        genre (string): Nome do gênero a ser buscado.
        filename (string): Nome do arquivo onde os filmes estão armazenados.

    Retorno:
        Retorna um gerador (iterável) com todos os filmes referentes ao gênero.

    Exceções:
        FileNotFoundError: Quando o arquivo indicado por `filename` não existir.
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
        reader = csv.DictReader(stream, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            if row['genre'].lower() == genre.lower():
                yield row
```

> Utilizei o método `lower()` para verificar o gênero para tornar a busca insensível ao caso, fazendo com que a busca por `Fantasia` retorne os mesmos resultados que `fantasia`, por exemplo.

Para exibir todos os filmes de um gênero lido do usuário, tal como é colocado na pergunta, podemos fazer:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    genre = input('Digite o gênero do filme: ')
    movies = search_by_genre(genre, filename='filmes.csv')
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie['name'])
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/RawDelightfulAmericanalligator)</sup>

Assim, executando o programa, teríamos:

```
Digite o gênero do filme: fantasia
O Hobbit
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz um IF-ELSE. Se o valor retornado de IF for false, a execução do programa pula para o bloco de código dentro de ELSE, daí dentro deste bloco de código você escreve o código de exibição de mensagem. Por exemplo:

```
if genero in str(linha[1]):
            print(linha[0])
else:
            print("Erro!")
```

Não sei se o ELSE escreve assim nesta linguagem, me desculpe. Mas a lógica é essa.

Comment: Neste caso, em qualquer iteração que não seja aquela que foi pesquisada, vai _printar_ "Erro!". Não deveria pesquisar todas e se não achou nenhuma imprimir a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Entendi. Vi sua resposta, você utilizou uma variável de controle e fez um IF fora do WHILE para checar se achou é true ou false.

Comment: Isso.. e o `else` é assim mesmo. Só indentar com 4 espaços ou um tab, não tenho certeza se assim funciona. A indentação no Python pode gerar erro de compilação, pois é assim que se definem os blocos =) @DouglasÖak

Comment: Legal @vnbrs, não sabia que em Python os blocos se organizam assim. Nunca escrevi nesta linguagem. Bom saber, porque, caso resolva me aventurar, estarei menos perdido haha.